# ¿ Cómo puedo multiplicar la diagonal de una matriz sin que me afecte los demás valores fuera de la diagonal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

escribo este ejercicio pidiendo alguna ayuda para poder terminar el ejercicio.

Tengo que hacer una función que me multiplique solo la diagonal de una matriz sin que me afecte los demás elementos de la matriz.

```
X = np.array([[79, 45, 67,  8, 37],
               [47, 40,  5, 79, 86],
               [72, 25, 44, 45, 22],
               [12, 85,  8, 53, 28],
               [ 4, 37, 36, 40, 16]])

#Mi función la cree así pero me afecta los otros elementos, cómo puedo terminar mi función y que lo haga bien? en k=0 si le quito el 0 ya no me funciona. 

def doublediag(X):
  dia=np.eye(len(X),M=None, k=0)*2
  new=X*dia
  return new
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: existe otras formas de hacerlo, ademas eso solo te retorna `1` y `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa solución rápida es es no multiplicando `np.eye` por 2 sino que sumarle 1

```
dia = np.eye(len(X), M=None, k=0) * 2
new = X * dia
```

La matriz `np.eye` me da una diagonal de 1 y el resto 0, si multiplico eso por 2 tendré una matriz con diagonal 2 y el resto 0.
Si esa matriz (matriz diagonal) la multiplico por la matriz original obtendré cada valor de la matriz original multiplicado por el elemento correspondiente en `dia`, es decir como sabemos que `dia` tiene valores en 0 cualquier numero multiplicado por 0 da 0, así que si los elemento de `dia` que no son 0 es decir los que son 2 los multiplico por los valor de la matriz original, dando como resultado la una matriz cuyo diagonal es igual a la diagonal de la matriz original multiplicado por 2 y el resto de elemento multiplicaciones por 0 es decir 0.

Ahora sumando.

```
dia = np.eye(len(X), M=None, k=0) + 1
new = X * dia
```

`np.eye` de dará una matriz con diagonal 1  y el resto de elementos 0, si a esa matriz se sumo 1, tendré una matriz cuya diagonal sea 2 y el resto de elementos 1, así que si multiplico `dia` por la matriz original obtendré cada elemento de la matriz original multiplicado por 1 es decir igual al valor original y los que se encentren en la diagonal multiplicado por 2.

Comment: Es que debo duplicar la diagonal, es decir multiplicar por dos la diagonal y que el resto de los elementos queden intactos.

Comment: Pero eso funciona, pruébelo.

Comment: Sí ya funcionó, pero no entiendo por qué, me podrías porfa explicar?, es que yo lo veo como si a la matriz le sumara un uno es decir 79 queda en 80 y así sucesivamente.  Es porque le sumo los mismos valores ? es como si se duplicara solo esas ubicaciones cierto?

Comment: Otra solución menos elegante.
`return np.array([[X[i][j] * 2 if i == j else X[i][j]  for j in range(len(X[i]))] for i in range(len(X))])`

Comment: esa compresion de lista se puede simplificar

Comment: @Christian Muchas gracias ya entendí lo que mencionas arriba.